# JavaScript - How to Wait / SetTimeOut / Sleep / Delay

Tags: javascript, delay

This again is my Rock Paper Scissors game.

At present state the user can't see what's happening because after being prompted for input(Rock, Paper or Scissors) they are immediately reprompted.

The question is how can I make the program delay such that they at least can read what's going on.

I've read that sleep() does not exist in JavaScript. I'm trying to use setTimeOut however, the setTimeOut is causing the program to not run.

**Any ideas on how I can delay the next user input after the first user input. This can be done via any JS solution.**

This is my present code

```
function playUntil(rounds) {
        var playerWins = 0;
        var computerWins = 0;
        setTimeout(function() {
        while ((playerWins < rounds) && (computerWins < rounds)) {
          var computerMove = getComputerMove();
          var winner = getWinner(playerMove, computerMove);
          console.log('The player has chosen ' + playerMove + '. The computer has chosen ' + computerMove);
          if (winner === "Player") {
              playerWins += 1; 
          } 
          else if (winner === "Computer") {
              computerWins += 1;
          } 
          if ((playerWins == rounds) || (computerWins == rounds)) {
              console.log("The game is over! The " + winner + " has taken out the game!");
              console.log("The final score was Player - [" + playerWins + "] to Computer - [" + computerWins + "]");
          }
          else {
              console.log(winner + ' takes the round. It is now ' + playerWins + ' to ' + computerWins);
          }
          }
      return [playerWins, computerWins]
    ;},5000);
    }
```

Comment: *"I'm trying to use setTimeOut however, it's throwing an error"*... and that error is?

Comment: The code you've shown doesn't even use `setTimeout`.

Comment: If your inputs to a tic tac toe game are rock, paper and scissors, then you have much bigger problems than this.

Comment: Guys don't vote down a question so quickly. Now it's simply not going to get answered and it's a very valid question

Comment: *setTimeout* only runs once. You can call it conditionally after each round, or use *setInterval* and cancel it after the last round.

Comment: Thankyou for the first non-troll answer @RobG. Looking into this now

Comment: Way too many trolls on SO

Answer (score -13, accepted):

This took me a long time to figure out but here was the solution.

Create this function

```
function sleep(miliseconds) {
    var currentTime = new Date().getTime();
    while (currentTime + miliseconds >= new Date().getTime()) {
    }
}
```

Add this into my code where I wanted the delay

```
sleep(3000)
```

Comment: Please don't do this - it freezes the entire page while sleeping.

Answer (score 24):

You cannot return a value for a parent function on a setTimeout, setInterval or another child function because have different scopes.

You can use promises instead: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Bad:

```
function x () {
  setTimeout(function () {
     return "anything";
  }, 5000);
}
```

Using promises:

```
function x () {
  return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(function () {
      resolve("anything");
    }, 5000);
  });
}
```

Then you can call function like:

```
x()
.then(
  function (result) {
    alert(result); // Do anything.
  }
);
```

PD: I have bad English, I'm sorry!.

Comment: Thanks jgdev, I'm just checking this solution now! :)

Comment: While promises are a good idea, they are a new feature in ECMAScript 2015 so not supported in a good many browsers in use (including IE). *setTimeout* and *setInterval* work everywhere.

Comment: Yes sorry I looked into this and people don't recommend it. Sorry jgdev.  I really appreciate the idea though! I'm still trying to work out how setTimeout or setInterval would work

Comment: You can use polyfill for those browsers (although by now all major browsers have support)