# Node js execute function before complete multiple lines of code

Tags: javascript, node.js, chatbot, watson-assistant, watson-discovery

This function:

```js
function print(){
  console.log('num 1')

  setTimeout(() => {
    global.name = 'max'
    console.log('num 2')
  },9000);

  console.log('num 3');
}
print();
console.log(global.name)
```

is priting this:

```
num 1
num 3
undefined
num 2
```

And I need to:

1. print  `num 1`
2. wait untill the  9 seconds
3. set the `global.name` = `max`
4. print `num 2`
5. print `num 3`
6. `console.log(global.name)`
7. print `max` and not `undefined`

I wrote this code in python and it executese line by line
because there is nothing called sync and async.

I need this code executed like python(line by line)

Comment: The code is being executed line by line. The `setTimeout()` API arranges for a function to be called at some time in the future, but `setTimeout()` itself returns immediately.

Comment: ok what if i need it to print ```num 1``` and make it wait untill the 9 seconds is ending then set the ```global.name``` = ```max``` then print ```num 2``` , ```num 3``` then by the ```console.log(global.name)``` print ```max``` and not ```undefined```

Comment: You need to use promise
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544073/javascript-how-to-wait-settimeout-sleep-delay

Comment: You need to use promise and or callback function
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35544073/javascript-how-to-wait-settimeout-sleep-delay

Comment: i know this, to understand what i mean please feel free to see this file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gkMBXOusP8k93fMvs7uFnSXAVP9CocBb/view here i set in the context ``` Discovery_context: global.Discovery_context``` i when i run this code the first time i get the global.Discovery_context is undefined so if you tried to print it outside the updateMessage function you will get undefined how can i fex this?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript code is executed line by line. If you wanna execute pieces of code you still need to put the given lines into the timeout like this:

```
let name = "Unknown";

function print() {
    console.log('num 1');

    setTimeout(() => {
        this.name = 'max';
        console.log('num 2');
        console.log('num 3');
        console.log(this.name);

    }, 900);


}

print();
```

Comment: i know this, to understand what i mean 
please feel free to see this file 
 https://drive.google.com/file/d/1gkMBXOusP8k93fMvs7uFnSXAVP9CocBb/view?usp=sharing
here i set in the context
```  Discovery_context: global.Discovery_context```
i when i run this code the first time i get the  ```global.Discovery_context``` is undefined so if you tried to print it outside the ```updateMessage``` function you will get undefined 
how can i fex this?

Answer (score 0):

The most readable way to work with synchronicity in JavaScript is with async functions. To give you an idea of what it can look like:

```
// To simulate the function you're going to use the snippet in
(async () => {

  async function print(){
    console.log('num 1')

    // await stops the execution until the setTimeout in sleep is done (non blocking)
    await sleep(9000);

    global.name = 'max'
    console.log('num 2')

    console.log('num 3');
  }

  // wait for the print function to finish
  await print();

  console.log(global.name)

})();

// Little utility function
function sleep(time) {
  return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, time))
}
```

You can read more about async/await here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function